# Beautiful Soup identifying elements

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am scraping the city of Denver Property Taxation pages and have a csv filled with addresses.

The URL is in the format https://www.denvergov.rg0/Property/?q=###%20DIR%20STREET%20SUFFIX%20. where the ### is street number, DIR is the N,E,S,W direction, STREET is the street name, Suffix  is the Place, Ave, etc.

example - https://www.denvergov.org/Property/?q=2420%20s%20humboldt%20st%20

So far my code is this:

```
url  = 'https://www.denvergov.org/Property/?q=2420%20s%20humboldt%20st%20'
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url) 
html_page = response.read() 
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page,"lxml") 

for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))
```

I had to remove what the output yields because it is a list of links that are not relevant to what I am looking for and github thinks it is spam.[So here is an image of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3cyu.png)

[Image of link that I am trying to pull](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJPrA.png)

However I am looking for this link that is circled in the image, or really even just the numbers at the end which are the parcel ID.

The end result would then take me to the page on the link and then over to the chain of title tab and pull the sale date and Sale price.

So my question is why when I find_all('a') is the link I am looking for not showing up?

I have tried different find_all ideas and tried to isolate the table but I am not having much luck. I am a new programmer.

Comment: Please post code, data, **and results** as text, not screenshots ([how to format code in posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)). [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: Aside: `requests.get()` is easier to use than `urllib`.

Comment: That URL is in `<script id="propertyTemplate" type="text/x-jQuery-tmpl">`. This tag isn't parsed as HTML. I think it's used by a jQuery plugin to update the page dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

The data is loaded from external URL via JavaScript, to get the link URL you can use next example:

```py
import requests

api_url = "https://www.denvergov.org/property/realproperty/search/search/0/"

params = {"searchText": "2420 s humboldt st ", "page": "1"}

data = requests.get(api_url, params=params).json()

# print(data)

for p in data["Properties"]:
    l = f'https://www.denvergov.org/property/realproperty/summary/{p["ScheduleNumber"]}/'
    print(p["Address"]["Street1"], l)
```

Prints:

```
2420 S HUMBOLDT ST  https://www.denvergov.org/property/realproperty/summary/0526510003000/
```